# How to close Indian Demat account?

Tags: investing, india, stock-exchanges

I am unable to close my Demat account, as I hold few shares of a company which is no longer traded in the market, my dp advised I have to transfer it to another Demat account if I wish to close it, I cant re materialize it as the company no longer has an active registrar
What can I do,  I don't want to pay annual maintenance charges and other incidental expenses in keping this Demat account.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard there are some Demat accounts which accepts such near nil vue shares as donation, which might gain value on resumption of trading and change of management.
Another solution is to write to promoters of these company (i tried no response, yet), or get someone to give exit offers for such shares   who will bid for this either inside or off market exchange. (Not aware of anyone).